# Azure maps clustering

Tags: azure-maps

I noticed in a recent iteration of Azure maps, pins can be added to a datasource which can be applied to a map's source -

```
var dataSource = new atlas.source.DataSource(); 
map.sources.add(dataSource);

dataSource.add(pins);
```

where `pins` is a collection of atlas.data.Feature elements.

The pins are successfully rendered onto the page in the correct locations, but they are clustered.

I don't want them clustered. At any given zoom level, I want to see all of my pins.

I tried to instantiate the datasource object like this (unclustered) -

```
                var dataSource = new atlas.source.DataSource(null, {
                    cluster: false
                });
```

but that didn't work.

At what level is the clustering set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clustering is turned off by default on the data source. What you are seeing is collision detection occurring between the symbols. This can be displayed by setting the allowOverlap and ignorePlacement icon options of the symbol layer.

```
var layer = new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, {
    iconOptions: {
        allowOverlap: true,
        ignorePlacement: true
    }
});
```

Comment: @rbrundritt  Thanks a lot nowhere in the documentation I could find this! By the way ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/

Comment: This is in a bunch of the code samples here: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html